# How to identify the current logged in user of a windows 10 machine

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I have developed a software, that requires current logged in user name, but during the installation, I provide the admin user( admin right user). my application fetches the admin user. is there any way to get the current user name/ details from the registry.

I tried to fetch the **HKEY_CURRENT_USER**, however, it returns the admin user profile.

Comment: We would need to understand the installation process, what happens before you provide the admin right user? how do you provide that? and why is that necessary? _(The obvious answer is to determine the user name before you change to 'another' user!)_ Your question is about developed software, but is specifically tagged [[tag:batch-file]] and [[tag:registry]]. From what you've provided there is no correlation between the two. In order to assist you we need to be able to replicate your issue, and you've not currently provided us with sufficient information for us to do that.

Comment: Does it have to be a batch script? This would be relatively easy in C/C++, or any scripting language that can use the Windows API, such as Python. Just query the session of the current process (`ProcessIdToSessionId`); impersonate SYSTEM (an admin can do this) and get the token of the session user (`WTSQueryUserToken`); and get the user name and/or user SID from the token (`GetTokenInformation`). Or impersonate the user's token (`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`) and call functions such as `RegOpenCurrentUser`.

Comment: `whoami` and `%username%`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure why you'd want to get this from the registry via batch file, but if you just want to get it in a batch file, just look at the `%username%` environment variable.  Alternatively if you want to get domain\machine information, check the output of `whoami`.  Lastly if you want a bit more information and want to parse it, you can use `Query user` but that would be decidedly more messy.

> C:\Users\myname>echo %username%
>
> myname

Or

> C:\Users\myname>whoami
>
> domain\myname

Comment: `%username%` and whoami.exe will be completely useless after an over-the-shoulder UAC elevation, which is required for a standard user to get admin access. It's a completely different logon session.

Comment: @ErykSun, the question doesn't mention requiring UAC elevation.  If that is the case, it would make more sense to get the logged in user before performing whatever task requires elevation.  Given that the OP is asking for a batch file solution, it's likely that there is a time during execution that is not yet elevated.

Comment: The problem description says "requires current logged in user name, but during the installation, I provide the admin user( admin right user)". The language could be clearer, but this is definitely an OTS elevation. It's not clear whether the OP has control over time of elevation. If the installer is flagged as requiring admin access, then the system will immediately prompt for elevation, in which case the process never runs as the session user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this what you want as to query the value of `LastUsedUsername` ?

```bat
@echo off
set "Winlogonkey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
@for /f "tokens=3 skip=2 delims= " %%a in (
'Reg Query "%Winlogonkey%" /v LastUsedUsername'
) do (
    Set "LastUsedUsername=%%a"
)
echo "%LastUsedUsername%"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am not seeing the LastUsedUsername key under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon. Another question- Is there a way to identify the current profile and last logged profile from the registry ?